# How do I create a table in SQL from this text file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a table in a database using SQL.  The data is currently in a text file that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsR2g.png), but has thousands of lines like that.

My trouble lies primarily in the parameters of the "CREATE TABLE" function.  Is there a way to say that I want all of the columns?  Right now the code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CFTC_Fin_Data
(

)

BULK INSERT dbo.CFTC_Fin_Data
    FROM 'H:\user\Desktop\CFTCData1.txt' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
    );
```

Thanks for any help.  I'm pretty new to SQL, so I apologize if similar questions have been answered already, but I couldn't understand any of the answers that I read.

Comment: I take it this is MS SQL? 'sql' by itself is a generic descriptor of MANY things database-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to look at your file and see what kind of info you have in each field.

With the line in your files, it seems that

Field1 is a string (3 char, maybe more in other lines) ? => `NVARCHAR(100)`

Field2 is a string (xx char) => `NVARCHAR(255)`

Field3 is a DATE  => DATE

Field4 seems to be all kind of things => `NVARCHAR(100)`

So something like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CTFC_Fin_Data (
column1 NVARCHAR(100),
column2 NVARCHAR(255),
column3 DATE,
column4 NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

But you need to examinate all your file to find the real right values and data types

**EDIT :**

In fact, your really need to do it with code ?

Cause with import-export wizard (in SQL Server Management Studio), you can import a data file, and the wizard can create the table for you if you need to.

Try :

Right-click on your database name, 
=> Tasks
 => Import Data

and follow the wizard.

You can also save the SSIS package if you need to.

Think it will be much more appropriate for you !

Comment: I'm getting the error message: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'column'".

Comment: So tell us the SGBD you're using, cause in SQL SERVER 2008 R2, I can use this code without any problem.

Comment: How do I find that out?  I'm using version 10.0.4000.0, and it says it's Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit)

Comment: Well, it means that you have SQL SERVER 2008. By the way, look at my edit, it should save you some time, maybe...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think for the time being that should be fine, but later on I'll need to do it through SQL because it's going to include real-time and constantly updating information.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 columns in your data file, you have to specify them:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CFTC_Fin_Data
(
column_name1 data_type,
column_name2 data_type,
column_name3 data_type,
column_name4 data_type
)
```

(Insert appropriate column names and data types)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a blanket statement that I could use to load every single column if I had, say, 100 of them?

Comment: I don't think so, the database cannot guess the type of your columns. Maybe you are confusing "columns" with "rows"?

Comment: No I know that what you typed works for this specific problem, but I'm asking if in general there's a way to write a statement that will load all of the columns regardless of how many?  I have other files with 70 or 80 columns, so I'm curious if there's an easier way then just writing them all out.

Comment: is there a specific table for specific file or you are after just importing each of the files separately into individual tables?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the  answers posted above , if your not restricted to  using Bulk insert than probably u can use openrowset . The advantage of using Openrowset is u can insert the values to a table which is created dynamically .Since the number of column varies u can try with the below syntax

```
 SELECT * INTO newTable

 FROM OPENROWSET(...)
```